# "in" vs. "on" a YouTube channel?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is the correct term, or can I use both?
I want to use it in a sentence like: "*Please stay on/in the channel*"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use *on* and not *in* when referring to such a channel.